# Flooded with logs from DistributedPubSubExtension

Tags: scala, akka

I am using akka along with DistributedPubSubExtension as a way to easily call multiple actors listening to an event. However, the objects I am sending through DistributedPubSubExtension are quite big and all of them are logged in the console. I suspect this behaviour is done by default (I used to do a lot of logging, but I cleaned it already, so it should not come from my code). This makes it impossible to find any other information within logs. Is there a way to turn off logging of all of the messages sent through this mediator?

Comment: What level are the messages from the pub/sub extension being logged at?

Comment: there is no information about level, they are just printed into the console. Or is there a way to determine the level? Right now I implemented the toString() method to return "" always, but it's a hack.

Comment: Unless specified in your code, you should check the logging level specified in the application akka config used. You can have the actor system print it out at its startup to check that you are not overriding stuff somewhere / see the unset default values.

Comment: Hi Diego, in the akka { I have loglevel = "WARNING", in the log level I have also logger.root=ERROR, logger.play=ERROR, logger.application=INFO. No other logging information there.